# super and base class should have different instances of same attribute name

Tags: python

I'm new to python, I'm trying to learn basic inheritance and I want the super and base class to have attributes with same name, but they should have different instances. Below is the code I've written to experiment with this Idea.

```
class master(object):

    def __init__(self, name):
        self.name = name

    def print_name(self):
        print (self.name)

class slave(master):

    def __init__(self, master_name, slave_name):

        self.name = slave_name
        super(slave, self).__init__(master_name)

    def print_name(self):

        super(slave, self).print_name()
        print (self.name)

def main():
    obj = slave('hello', 'world')
    obj.print_name()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

The out put I'm getting is :
hello
hello

But I want want the output to be 
world
hello

Answer (score 1):

Super class and base class are different names for the same thing, in this case the `master` class.  That is the base class for `slave` as well as its super class.

You could have an attribute with the same name on the *classes*, but not on *the* instance `obj`, which is an instance of `master` and `slave` at the same time.  So `self` in both methods `master.print_name()` and `slave.print_name()` refers to the very same object.

An attribute on an object can only be assigned one value at a given time, so you need different names.  But you can get the appearance of the same name with the name mangling that is done behind the scenes for attributes with two leading underscores:

```
class Master(object):

    def __init__(self, name):
        self.__name = name

    def print_name(self):
        print self.__name


class Slave(Master):

    def __init__(self, master_name, slave_name):

        self.__name = slave_name
        Master.__init__(self, master_name)

    def print_name(self):

        Master.print_name(self)
        print self.__name


def main():
    obj = Slave('hello', 'world')
    obj.print_name()
    # The *actual* names of the attributes:
    print obj._Master__name, obj._Slave__name


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Answer (score 0):

The `__init__` from `master` is overriding the value of `self.name` that you set in `slave`. You need to use different variable names.